# Can you iterate a number backwards without using a list?

Tags: python, list, iteration

How would you iterate a number backwards without using a list in Python 3?

Using lists, I would probably do something like:

```
li = list(range(100))
for i in li[::-1]:
    print(i)
```

This is a fine solution, but it does not work with huge numbers.
Right now, I'm trying to iterate a number backwards with large numbers, but an overflow error happens, so I think I need to somehow find a way to iterate a number backwards without using lists.

Is there any way?

Comment: Thanks everybody, now I solved problem 3 on Project Euler.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Iterators that provide the `__reversed__()` special method also support reversed iteration.  In Python 3.x, `range()` iterators have this method, so you can also use

```
for i in reversed(range(100)):
    print(i)
```

In Python 2.x, `xarnge()` allows reversed iteration:

```
for i in reversed(xrange(100)):
    print i
```

Both versions do not store the whole list in memory.

Comment: +1 As they say, one learns something new every day on SO. Too bad it's not widely supported.

Answer (score 2):

<del>Generally? No. Python's iterator protocol only supports forward iteration.</del>(Edit: This turned out to be incorrect, see Sven Marnach's answer.)

However, you can reverse `range(n, m)`: `range(m-1, n-1, -1)` (the -1 are ugly, yes, but it's necessary due to `range` returning a half-open range).

Comment: thanks for adding the '-1' to both m and n to make sure I have the same results as if I would have used li[::-1]

Comment: @John: I suggest you accept Sven Marnach's answer instead. My suggestion is unnecessarily cryptic and contained misleading information.

Comment: "Generally? No." is still correct.  Most iterators are not going to implement the reversed iteration protocol.

Comment: @wnoise: `reversed` works for all sequences and a few others (including most where reversing makes sense) though, so it *is* possible without creating a whole list in most cases.

Answer (score 1):

Try using range]and step down...

```
for i in range(100, 0, -1):
```

*[update] I just noticed that you said Python 3, in which case you can just use range instead of xrange.*

Comment: Sadly, reversing `range` requires a bit more. And this is Python 3, i.e. `range = xrange; del xrange`.

Comment: @deinan: Thanks, I didn't realize Python 3 did that (I really need to ditch my 2.7 habits).

Comment: `range` is actually more list-like than `xrange` ever was, though (especially in 3.2). The general idea is still the same (i.e. calculate the range contents on the fly rather than realising the whole sequence in memory), but it provides quite a few more features (efficient containment testing for integers, good slicing support, implements the Sequence ABC, supports ranges larger than `sys.maxint`).

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in range(10,0,-1):
    print(i)
```